# Sending many objects via Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, object, tcp, pickle

What is the proper way to send multiple objects using the Python Socket?
My Server gets data from MySQL database, then sends it one by one to the Client. This is done using the Pickle method:
**pickle data**

```
def serializeData(self, ID, first_name, last_name):
    # create instance of Person object
    person = sd.Person(ID, first_name, last_name)

    # serialize object to make it possible to send via Socket
    data = pickle.dumps(person)

    return data
```

**Server**

```
# query from database
self.sql_cursor.execute("select * from employees")
# send data via Socket
for x in self.sql_cursor:
connection.send(self.serializeData(str(x[0]), x[2], x[3]))
```

Client receives byte stream, then decodes it, using Pickle.
**Client**

```
def deserializeData(self, received_data):
    deserialized_data = pickle.loads(received_data)

    return deserialized_data
```

```
while True:
    self.data += s.recv(1024)
    person = self.deserializeData(self.data)

    if self.data:
        print("ID: " + person.ID)
        print("First name: " + person.first_name)
        print("Last name: " + person.last_name)
    else:
        break
```

It works for the first object, but after this, the Client throws an unpickling error:

```
ID: 10001
First name: Georgi
Last name: Facello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Client.py", line 54, in <module>
    client.connectAndFetchData()
  File "./Client.py", line 38, in connectAndFetchData
    person = self.deserializeData(data)
  File "./Client.py", line 20, in deserializeData
    deserialized_data = pickle.loads(received_data)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

What can be a problem?

Comment: The problem is this line `self.data += s.recv(1024)`. You don't analyze what `s.recv(1024)` call returns. It can return data of any size between 0 and 1024, with 0 meaning the connection is closed. You also don't take lags into consideration, partial data and many other things that may happen over the wire. You need some protocol, you cannot just send data over the wire, that doesn't work. There's a lot about networking for you to learn. But why do you even bother with all of the low level stuff? Can't you just use some lib that does that for you, e.g. some websocket lib?

Comment: Are you aware that socket.recv(n) returns *up to* n bytes, meaning you may receive less? Are you aware that sockets are not message based, meaning that a single socket.recv call may fetch data from multiple objects? Did you read the Python socket howto, or any other tutorial how to send messages via sockets?

Comment: Don't use pickle in communication! Pickle data can easily be manipulated to a remote code execution.